# asp.net mvc implicit population of input fields

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In our asp.net mvc I've created view with two partial views inside.
That view accepts model of some type, for example Customer.
First partial view doesn't have model because it is search form with empty field.
Second form is form with populated fields.
What I found out that on first view, if I have called input fields like properties in model and if I don't provide value for them, mvc implicitly binds values from model to the fields.
First I was thinking is some of kind of mistake, but then I've expiremented little bit with a code:

-I've added native input element with id and name called the same like model, input field is empty in browser
-If I try the same thing with Html.TextBox helper and don't provide value, mvc gets that value from my model object(by name of property/field) and in browser that field is populated.

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Thanx

Comment: Could you please show your code? I think it will be more explicit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is by design. If you send a model to a view *and* you're using the HTML input Helpers that come with ASP.NET MVC, they'll implicitly populate themselves from the model.

This is helpful in many situations. If you don't want this behavior, you can always NOT use the helpers or write your own simple helpers.

Answer (score 2):

That's by design.

I'd recomend reading:

- http://asp.net/mvc
- http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/tags/MVC/default.aspx

and last but not least:

- http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/MIX

especially mix10 has a tonn of sessions about mvc
all are good read and watch (-:

Comment: hm, I read fair amount of articles and videos but I didn't come across this particular problem...so, you recommend to read and watch all of that first and then do asp.net mvc? :) :)

Comment: well Html.Helpers are basic stuff  to render model. I thought that if you missed that, maybe it is a good time to recap.

Comment: sorry, I wanted to mark your answer but you added little cynicism into it.. ;) here you go, I will give you one up vote